# Reset a form except one field with Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms

For some reason, I need to reset a form but I want one field to remain unchanged.

This following code clears all the fields but I would like to keep the first one unchanged.

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input id="01" type="text"/>
    <input id="02" type="text"/>
    <input id="03" type="text"/>
    <input id="04" type="text"/>
</form>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('myForm').reset()">Reset</button>
```

If possible, I would like to avoid jQuery.

Comment: [Another question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34906790/4342563) was recently marked as a duplicate of this question, which brought me here.  However, it seems this question was a duplicate of a [similar question posed in March](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22697157/4342563).  I wouldn't doubt the same thing had been asked before that - but that's enough meta-research for me today.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Copy its value to a variable. Reset the form. Reassign the variable back to the value.

Comment: But if there are events bound to the form field which needs to retain its value - might be a problem, because this field will change its value before getting it back...

Answer (score 2):

I had been working on an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34906790/4342563), which is similar, and has now been marked as a duplicate.  That question was using `jQuery`, so the answer would have been much shorter, leveraging things like `event.data`, `detach()`, etc.  Below is the general algorithm, and a vanilla version of the approach I would take to handle not just this question's but also more complex scenarios where you want to exclude an entire subsection of a form.

---

### The algorithm

1. Detach the element from it's parent
2. Allow the default `reset()` behavior
3. Reattach the element in the correct location within the DOM

---

Here is a very simple translation of that plan in to code.  This doesn't actually re-attach the element in the right location within the DOM.  Please see the code snippet for a fully functional example.

```
// within the form's onreset handler, which fires
// before the form's children are actually reset

var form = document.getElementById("myForm"),
    exclude = document.getElementById("_01"),
    parentNode = exclude.parentNode;

parentNode.removeChild(exclude);

// use a timeout to allow the default reset() behavior
// before re-attaching the element
setTimeout(function() { parentNode.appendChild(exclude); });
```

**NOTE** the `id` change to `_01`, and refer to the "Side note" at the end of this answer for more info on that.

---

### Important properties and methods

- [`.parentNode`](http://www.w3schools.com/XML/prop_element_parentnode.asp)
- [`.nextSibling`](http://www.w3schools.com/XML/prop_element_nextsibling.asp)
- [`.removeChild()`](http://www.w3schools.com/XML/met_element_removechild.asp)
- [`.appendChild()`](http://www.w3schools.com/XML/met_element_appendchild.asp)
- [`.insertBefore()`](http://www.w3schools.com/XML/met_element_insertbefore.asp)

---

```js
var dataKey = 'data-exclude-selector';

function initiateReset(e) {
  e = e || window.event;

  var button = e.target,
    form = button.form,
    excludeSelector = button.getAttribute(dataKey);

  form.setAttribute(dataKey, excludeSelector);
}

function beforeReset(e) {
  e = e || window.event;

  var form = e.target,
    excludeSelector = form.getAttribute(dataKey),
    elements = form.querySelectorAll(excludeSelector),
    parents = [],
    siblings = [],
    len = elements.length,
    i, e, p, s;

  // When reset #5 is clicked, note the excludeSelector's value is js escaped:
  // #\0030\0035 element attribute value becomes #\\0030\\0035 as js var value

  for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    el = elements[i];
    parents.push(p = el.parentNode);
    siblings.push(s = el.nextSibling);
    p.removeChild(el);
  }

  setTimeout(function() {
    for (var j = 0; j < len; j++) {
      if (siblings[j]) {
        parents[j].insertBefore(elements[j], siblings[j]);
      } else {
        parents[j].appendChild(elements[j]);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm" onreset="beforeReset()" data-exclude-selector="">
  <input id="_01" type="text" placeholder="clear" />
  <br />
  <input id="_02" type="text" placeholder="clear" />
  <br />
  <input id="_03" type="text" placeholder="clear" />
  <br />
  <input id="_04" type="text" placeholder="clear" />
  <br />
  <input id="05" type="text" placeholder="clear" />
</form>
<input value="Reset 1" type="reset" form="myForm" data-exclude-selector="#_01" onclick="initiateReset()" />
<input value="Reset 2" type="reset" form="myForm" data-exclude-selector="#_02" onclick="initiateReset()" />
<input value="Reset 3" type="reset" form="myForm" data-exclude-selector="#_03" onclick="initiateReset()" />
<input value="Reset 4" type="reset" form="myForm" data-exclude-selector="#_04" onclick="initiateReset()" />
<input value="Reset funky ID (05)" type="reset" form="myForm" data-exclude-selector="#\0030\0035" onclick="initiateReset()" />
<br/>&nbsp;
<br />
<hr/>
<br/>
<form id="complexForm" onreset="beforeReset()" data-exclude-selector="">
  <input class="exclude" type="text" placeholder="clear" />
  <br />
  <input class="exclude" type="text" placeholder="clear" />
  <br />
  <input type="text" placeholder="clear" />
  <br />
  <input type="text" placeholder="clear" />
  <br />
  <div class="childTest">
    <input type="text" placeholder="clear" />
    <br />
    <input type="text" placeholder="clear" />
    <div class="nestedTest">
      <input type="text" placeholder="clear" />
      <br />
      <input type="text" placeholder="clear" />
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
<input value="Exclude by class" type="reset" form="complexForm" data-exclude-selector=".exclude" onclick="initiateReset()" />
<input value="Exclude subsection" type="reset" form="complexForm" data-exclude-selector=".childTest" onclick="initiateReset()" />
```

---

### Additional work

- More work will need to be done to handle the case where one would want to allow reset on certain children of excluded nodes, but I imagine this could be handled in multiple different ways with a little thought

  1. a recursive version of this idea
  2. @Quentin's idea could be extended using [`cloneNode()`](http://www.w3schools.com/XML/met_element_clonenode.asp) to make a copy of the entire node, instead of detaching it, allow a full reset, then implement a mechanism to determine which portions of the clone to systematically restore

---

### Side note (...rant?)

- Although the [HTML5 `id` attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute) allows for `01` as valid, the spec does go on to indicate that it can be used for other purposes.

> 3.2.5.1 The *id* attribute
>
> The [id](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute) attribute specifies its element's [unique identifier (ID)](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#concept-id). [[DOM]](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/references.html#refsDOM)
>
> The value must be unique amongst all the [IDs](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#concept-id) in the element's [home
>   subtree](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#home-subtree) and must contain at least one character. The value must not
>   contain any [space characters](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#space-character).
>
> > **Note:** There are no other restrictions on what form an ID can take; in
> >     particular, IDs can consist of just digits, start with a digit, start
> >     with an underscore, consist of just punctuation, etc.
> >
> > **Note:** An element's [unique identifier](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#concept-id) can be used for a variety of purposes,
> >     most notably as a way to link to specific parts of a document using
> >     fragment identifiers, as a way to target an element when scripting,
> >     and as a way to style a specific element from CSS.

This may not be a problem for you, but it is something to be aware of.  For instance, [`document.querySelector[All]()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FDocument.querySelectorAll) uses CSS style selectors.

> `elementList = document.querySelectorAll(selectors);`
>
> ...
>
> - selectors is a string containing one or more [CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors) separated by commas.

According to the [latest draft of the CSS Selectors spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#id-selectors)

> An ID selector contains a "number sign" (U+0023, #) immediately followed by the ID value, which must be an CSS [identifiers](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier).

And at the end of the rabbit hole are the rules for [CSS identifiers](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier)

> - In CSS, *identifiers* (including element names, classes, and IDs in [selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html)) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646 characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore (_); they cannot start with a digit, two hyphens, or a hyphen followed by a digit. Identifiers can also contain escaped characters and any ISO 10646 character as a numeric code (see next item). For instance, the identifier "B&W?" may be written as "B\&W\?" or "B\26 W\3F".
>
>   Note that Unicode is code-by-code equivalent to ISO 10646 (see [[UNICODE]](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/refs.html#ref-UNICODE) and  [[ISO10646]](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/refs.html#ref-ISO10646)).

So if you're only using `document.getElementById()` you might be ok with an element `id` value like `01`, but in general I would avoid it.  Yes, with `document.querySelector[All]()`, and any other component that uses CSS style selectors you *may be able to* get around this limitation by escaping the selector correctly, but this is a pitfall waiting to happen, especially if multiple developers are involved.  I've included an example (5th reset button) in the code snippet for completion, if you *have* to interact with elements that have IDs taking a format like this.

[Reference table for hex codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_646)

Comment: I should have kept looking, this question is a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22697157/4342563) to a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10395665/4342563) to a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5716642/4342563) dating back to April '11.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following code :

```
var form = document.getElementById("myForm");
var inputs = form.getElementsByTagName("input")

for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if(i != 0) {
        inputs[i].value = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: This will work … for this specific case. It won't work in the general case as it will fail on non-inputs and and will wipe instead of reset inputs with non-blank default values (including the labels of submit inputs).

Comment: You're right but in this situation only the content use input elements, he is using a button element to execute the javascript and he could use it too to submit the form.

Comment: I said that in the first sentence of my comment. It's still bad practice and likely to cause problems in the future if the requirements for the form change.

Answer (score 0):

Store the value the one value in variable

Var partNumber=document.getElementById('partNumber').value;

Then reset the form

document.getElementById('form').reset();

Then reasign the value

document.getElementById('partNumber').value=partNumber;

Answer (score 0):

```
  var temp_c = $('#name').val(); //Select input by id
     $('#myForm')[0].reset();
     $('#name').val(temp_c);
```

Comment: The question is not about jQuery. Maybe you can rework your answer with a vaniliajs solution?